# evaulate expression tree with logical operation in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, conditional-statements, expression

```
List<Condition> conditions = new List<Condition>()
{
    new Condition
    {
        sourcetype = "a",
        datatype = 2,
        condition = 4,
        threshold = 3,
        index = 0
    },
    new Condition
    {
        sourcetype = "b",
        datatype = 2,
        condition = 4,
        threshold = 34,
        index = 1
    },
    new Condition
    {
        sourcetype = "b",
        datatype = 2,
        condition = 4,
        threshold = 34,
        index = 2
    }
};
```

I have a Condition List like above in my C# code.
Each of these Condition objects can return a bool value by entering the IsValid(Condition c) method.

Let's assume that when we put the values in the List into the IsValid method one by one, it gives the following results for the index parameters.

```
index = 0 -> true,
index = 1 -> false,
index = 2 -> false,
index = 3 -> true
```

What I want to do is take an expression string and combine them and get a result.
I want to do these operations like a mathematical operation. The operation inside the parentheses must be done first.

Expression strings and their results should be as follows:

0|(1&2) -> say true or (1 and 2) and should return true.

1&(0|2|3) -> say false and (0 or 2 or 3) and should result in true.

Can you write a code that can do the above comparisons by taking this List and expressionTree string?

Answer (score 0):

If your `IsValid()` method receives the entire model as a parameter, then you should pass each model to perform bitwise operator calculations like this:

```
var result = IsValid(conditions[0]) | (IsValid(conditions[1]) & IsValid(conditions[2]));
return result;
```

Result:
[image]

If you want to pass an expression like `1&(0|2|3)` directly, I suggest that you process the expression as a string and receive only one parameter of type int in the `IsValid()` method.

For example:

Right click on the project -> Add -> COM Reference, then select `Microsoft Script Control 1.0`:
[image]

Then you can create a method that takes the expression and evaluates it after processing:

```
public bool Computed(string str)
{
    str = "1&(0|2|3)";
    string r = @"[0-9]+";
    Regex reg = new Regex(r, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    MatchCollection mc = reg.Matches(str);
    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        str = str.Replace(m.Groups[0].Value, IsValid(int.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value)).ToString().ToLower());
    }
    MSScriptControl.ScriptControl scc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
    scc.Language = "JavaScript";
    var result = scc.Eval(str);
    if (result == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
private bool IsValid(int index)
{
    bool TrueOrFalse;
    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            TrueOrFalse = true;
            return true;
        case 1:
            TrueOrFalse = false;
            return false;
        case 2:
            TrueOrFalse = false;
            return false;
        case 3:
            TrueOrFalse = false;
            return true;
        default:
            TrueOrFalse = true;
            break;
    }
    return TrueOrFalse;
}
```

Result(1 is true, 0 is false):

[image]

If you get this error: `80040154 Class not registered`, please try to change target platform to `x86`, instead of the default `Any CPU`:

[image]

Is this what you want?